# Large SATA hard drive for Intellistation A Pro 6217

Tags: hard-drive, sata

I posted this question to the IBM forums, but got no response!  I'm hoping someone here will be able to help.

I have recently become the lucky new owner of an Intellistation A Pro 6217. I would like to install some large SATA disks, but have not been able to find information regrading any limits on drive size that the BIOS supports. I have upgraded the BIOS from PXJT125 to PXE136A, which I believe to be the most recent BIOS.

The documentation I've seen shows that IBM supplied SATA disks as large as 500GB - has anyone successfully installed drives larger than this?

Before I splash out on a couple of drives, can anyone offer advice on what is likely (or unlikely!) to work. I'm hoping to put a pair of 1.5TB drives in if possible.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Barring some fluke drive incompatibility, that workstation should support all SATA drives on the market today (limited to 1.5Gbps). It's got a Silicon Image 3512A SATA chipset (which is none too impressive, but works well enough).

Comment: Thanks Chris - unless I get advice to the contrary, I'll give it a go in the next couple of week and report back here with my findings.

Comment: Worked without a problem.  It's now sporting two 1.5TB SATA drives.